# How to host Spring boot application on cpanel?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cpanel, war, vps

I have a Spring boot application and i want to host it in my VPS server (cpanel).
I'am using the last version of cpanel & WHM with easyapache 4.

I exactly followed the steps on this website : https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-war-file-in-easy-apache-4-tomcat-experim

But, nothing on the result. I got Error 404 when i access to my domain name.

If anyone can help me on this or anyone done this before could give the exact steps to follow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty with that too, use the link in the attachment that you will have an orientation, but it may be that not everything is 100% the same. If you have any questions during the process, you can contact!

> change the name of the .war file to `ROOT.war` , and follow all the procedures described in the link;

> In the "application.properties" file, add the "server.port" configuration for the port you found in the link (step 2, part 1).
>
> ex: `server.port=10003`

> Open the file "ea-tomcat85/logs/catalina.out" to see the errors thrown

link: https://suporte.hostgator.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/360038980913-Como-configurar-o-Tomcat-