# How to deploy my Spring Boot application in these circumstances?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vps

**Introduction**

I have a VPS ***CENTOS 7.9 kvm*** running WHM and ***cPanel v98.0.7***.

I have a spring boot application to be deployed.

This application was made to be deployed in a sub-domain of a hosted domain in this WHM.

**Problem**

How do I deploy a spring boot application to a subdomain in cPanel on my VPS?

**References**

[How to host Spring boot application on cpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683588/how-to-host-spring-boot-application-on-cpanel)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps?r=SearchResults&s=1|118.4887](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C118.4887)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933273/spring-boot-2-on-vps-cant-be-accessed?r=SearchResults&s=2|112.0267](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933273/spring-boot-2-on-vps-cant-be-accessed?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C112.0267)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=VPS+spring+boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution applied to my hostgator VPS.
Consider:

ACCOUNT_NAME to be your account name;
DOMAIN_NAME to be your domain name. It can also be a subdomain;

1. Backup your apache settings:

> cp -vp /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf{,-BKP}

2. Uncomment the lines of include in the vhost of the domain. Do it for the HTTP(std) and for the HTTPS(ssl):

> vim /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

3. Once you accessed the file, search the following lines and remove the #

> Include
> "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/*.conf"
> Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/*.conf"

4. Create the following directories:

> ```
> mkdir -p /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME
> mkdir -p /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME
> ```

5. Create a .conf for std and ssl.

> ```
> vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/ACCOUNT_NAME.conf
>
> vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/ACCOUNT_NAME.conf
> ```

6. 

> /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/ACCOUNT_NAME.conf
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ProxyPass "/" "http://DOMAIN_NAME:10002/"
> ```

7. 

> /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/ACCOUNT_NAME/DOMAIN_NAME/ACCOUNT_NAME.conf
>
> ```
> ProxyPass "/" "http://DOMAIN_NAME:10002/"
> ```

8. Once you are done, restart the httpd service.

> service httpd restart